# I have a C++ DLL type project in Visual Studio 2012 Pro but I can't compile it as CLR - Why is that?

Tags: c++, c, dll, clr

I have a C++ project which is DLL type with a C file I created inside.
Now I need to use CLR since I want to use the DLL later on .NET C#.

Now in the general project properties I have:

```
Target Extension: .dll
Configuration Type: Dynamic Library (.dll)
```

Common Language Runtime Support: (before it was No Common Language Runtime Support) and when compiling it was without any errors but I couldn't add the DLL on the hard disk to my C# project.

Now I changed this to: `Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)`

But now when I try to compile the project I get this error:

> Error 1   error D8045: cannot compile C file 'ENCODER.C' with the /clr
>   option

The file `encode.c` contain c language content. If I compile it without CLR there are no errors but I can't add the DLL to my .NET C# project later.

I also tried to change in C/C++ > Advanced > Compile As: Compile as C Code (/TC)
Bu it didn't fix the error.

What else can I do?

This is the common.h file content:

```
/*
 * copyright (c) 2006 Michael Niedermayer <michaelni@gmx.at>
 *
 * This file is part of FFmpeg.
 *
 * FFmpeg is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
 * version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * FFmpeg is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
 * Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License along with FFmpeg; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301 USA
 */

/**
 * @file
 * common internal and external API header
 */

#ifndef AVUTIL_COMMON_H
#define AVUTIL_COMMON_H

#include <errno.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "attributes.h"
#include "version.h"
#include "libavutil/avconfig.h"

#if AV_HAVE_BIGENDIAN
#   define AV_NE(be, le) (be)
#else
#   define AV_NE(be, le) (le)
#endif

//rounded division & shift
#define RSHIFT(a,b) ((a) > 0 ? ((a) + ((1<<(b))>>1))>>(b) : ((a) + ((1<<(b))>>1)-1)>>(b))
/* assume b>0 */
#define ROUNDED_DIV(a,b) (((a)>0 ? (a) + ((b)>>1) : (a) - ((b)>>1))/(b))
#define FFUDIV(a,b) (((a)>0 ?(a):(a)-(b)+1) / (b))
#define FFUMOD(a,b) ((a)-(b)*FFUDIV(a,b))
#define FFABS(a) ((a) >= 0 ? (a) : (-(a)))
#define FFSIGN(a) ((a) > 0 ? 1 : -1)

#define FFMAX(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
#define FFMAX3(a,b,c) FFMAX(FFMAX(a,b),c)
#define FFMIN(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (b) : (a))
#define FFMIN3(a,b,c) FFMIN(FFMIN(a,b),c)

#define FFSWAP(type,a,b) do{type SWAP_tmp= b; b= a; a= SWAP_tmp;}while(0)
#define FF_ARRAY_ELEMS(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))
#define FFALIGN(x, a) (((x)+(a)-1)&~((a)-1))

/* misc math functions */

/**
 * Reverse the order of the bits of an 8-bits unsigned integer.
 */
#if FF_API_AV_REVERSE
extern attribute_deprecated const uint8_t av_reverse[256];
#endif

#ifdef HAVE_AV_CONFIG_H
#   include "config.h"
#   include "intmath.h"
#endif

/* Pull in unguarded fallback defines at the end of this file. */
#include "common.h"

#ifndef av_log2
av_const int av_log2(unsigned v);
#endif

#ifndef av_log2_16bit
av_const int av_log2_16bit(unsigned v);
#endif

/**
 * Clip a signed integer value into the amin-amax range.
 * @param a value to clip
 * @param amin minimum value of the clip range
 * @param amax maximum value of the clip range
 * @return clipped value
 */
static av_always_inline av_const int av_clip_c(int a, int amin, int amax)
{
#if defined(HAVE_AV_CONFIG_H) && defined(ASSERT_LEVEL) && ASSERT_LEVEL >= 2
    if (amin > amax) abort();
#endif
    if      (a < amin) return amin;
    else if (a > amax) return amax;
    else               return a;
}

/**
 * Clip a signed 64bit integer value into the amin-amax range.
 * @param a value to clip
 * @param amin minimum value of the clip range
 * @param amax maximum value of the clip range
 * @return clipped value
 */
static av_always_inline av_const int64_t av_clip64_c(int64_t a, int64_t amin, int64_t amax)
{
#if defined(HAVE_AV_CONFIG_H) && defined(ASSERT_LEVEL) && ASSERT_LEVEL >= 2
    if (amin > amax) abort();
#endif
    if      (a < amin) return amin;
    else if (a > amax) return amax;
    else               return a;
}

/**
 * Clip a signed integer value into the 0-255 range.
 * @param a value to clip
 * @return clipped value
 */
static av_always_inline av_const uint8_t av_clip_uint8_c(int a)
{
    if (a&(~0xFF)) return (-a)>>31;
    else           return a;
}

/**
 * Clip a signed integer value into the -128,127 range.
 * @param a value to clip
 * @return clipped value
 */
static av_always_inline av_const int8_t av_clip_int8_c(int a)
{
    if ((a+0x80) & ~0xFF) return (a>>31) ^ 0x7F;
    else                  return a;
}

/**
 * Clip a signed integer value into the 0-65535 range.
 * @param a value to clip
 * @return clipped value
 */
static av_always_inline av_const uint16_t av_clip_uint16_c(int a)
{
    if (a&(~0xFFFF)) return (-a)>>31;
    else             return a;
}

/**
 * Clip a signed integer value into the -32768,32767 range.
 * @param a value to clip
 * @return clipped value
 */
static av_always_inline av_const int16_t av_clip_int16_c(int a)
{
    if ((a+0x8000) & ~0xFFFF) return (a>>31) ^ 0x7FFF;
    else                      return a;
}

/**
 * Clip a signed 64-bit integer value into the -2147483648,2147483647 range.
 * @param a value to clip
 * @return clipped value
 */
static av_always_inline av_const int32_t av_clipl_int32_c(int64_t a)
{
    if ((a+0x80000000u) & ~UINT64_C(0xFFFFFFFF)) return (a>>63) ^ 0x7FFFFFFF;
    else                                         return (int32_t)a;
}

/**
 * Clip a signed integer to an unsigned power of two range.
 * @param  a value to clip
 * @param  p bit position to clip at
 * @return clipped value
 */
static av_always_inline av_const unsigned av_clip_uintp2_c(int a, int p)
{
    if (a & ~((1<<p) - 1)) return -a >> 31 & ((1<<p) - 1);
    else                   return  a;
}

/**
 * Add two signed 32-bit values with saturation.
 *
 * @param  a one value
 * @param  b another value
 * @return sum with signed saturation
 */
static av_always_inline int av_sat_add32_c(int a, int b)
{
    return av_clipl_int32((int64_t)a + b);
}

/**
 * Add a doubled value to another value with saturation at both stages.
 *
 * @param  a first value
 * @param  b value doubled and added to a
 * @return sum with signed saturation
 */
static av_always_inline int av_sat_dadd32_c(int a, int b)
{
    return av_sat_add32(a, av_sat_add32(b, b));
}

/**
 * Clip a float value into the amin-amax range.
 * @param a value to clip
 * @param amin minimum value of the clip range
 * @param amax maximum value of the clip range
 * @return clipped value
 */
static av_always_inline av_const float av_clipf_c(float a, float amin, float amax)
{
#if defined(HAVE_AV_CONFIG_H) && defined(ASSERT_LEVEL) && ASSERT_LEVEL >= 2
    if (amin > amax) abort();
#endif
    if      (a < amin) return amin;
    else if (a > amax) return amax;
    else               return a;
}

/** Compute ceil(log2(x)).
 * @param x value used to compute ceil(log2(x))
 * @return computed ceiling of log2(x)
 */
static av_always_inline av_const int av_ceil_log2_c(int x)
{
    return av_log2((x - 1) << 1);
}

/**
 * Count number of bits set to one in x
 * @param x value to count bits of
 * @return the number of bits set to one in x
 */
static av_always_inline av_const int av_popcount_c(uint32_t x)
{
    x -= (x >> 1) & 0x55555555;
    x = (x & 0x33333333) + ((x >> 2) & 0x33333333);
    x = (x + (x >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F;
    x += x >> 8;
    return (x + (x >> 16)) & 0x3F;
}

/**
 * Count number of bits set to one in x
 * @param x value to count bits of
 * @return the number of bits set to one in x
 */
static av_always_inline av_const int av_popcount64_c(uint64_t x)
{
    return av_popcount((uint32_t)x) + av_popcount(x >> 32);
}

#define MKTAG(a,b,c,d) ((a) | ((b) << 8) | ((c) << 16) | ((unsigned)(d) << 24))
#define MKBETAG(a,b,c,d) ((d) | ((c) << 8) | ((b) << 16) | ((unsigned)(a) << 24))

/**
 * Convert a UTF-8 character (up to 4 bytes) to its 32-bit UCS-4 encoded form.
 *
 * @param val      Output value, must be an lvalue of type uint32_t.
 * @param GET_BYTE Expression reading one byte from the input.
 *                 Evaluated up to 7 times (4 for the currently
 *                 assigned Unicode range).  With a memory buffer
 *                 input, this could be *ptr++.
 * @param ERROR    Expression to be evaluated on invalid input,
 *                 typically a goto statement.
 */
#define GET_UTF8(val, GET_BYTE, ERROR)\
    val= GET_BYTE;\
    {\
        uint32_t top = (val & 128) >> 1;\
        if ((val & 0xc0) == 0x80)\
            ERROR\
        while (val & top) {\
            int tmp= GET_BYTE - 128;\
            if(tmp>>6)\
                ERROR\
            val= (val<<6) + tmp;\
            top <<= 5;\
        }\
        val &= (top << 1) - 1;\
    }

/**
 * Convert a UTF-16 character (2 or 4 bytes) to its 32-bit UCS-4 encoded form.
 *
 * @param val       Output value, must be an lvalue of type uint32_t.
 * @param GET_16BIT Expression returning two bytes of UTF-16 data converted
 *                  to native byte order.  Evaluated one or two times.
 * @param ERROR     Expression to be evaluated on invalid input,
 *                  typically a goto statement.
 */
#define GET_UTF16(val, GET_16BIT, ERROR)\
    val = GET_16BIT;\
    {\
        unsigned int hi = val - 0xD800;\
        if (hi < 0x800) {\
            val = GET_16BIT - 0xDC00;\
            if (val > 0x3FFU || hi > 0x3FFU)\
                ERROR\
            val += (hi<<10) + 0x10000;\
        }\
    }\

/**
 * @def PUT_UTF8(val, tmp, PUT_BYTE)
 * Convert a 32-bit Unicode character to its UTF-8 encoded form (up to 4 bytes long).
 * @param val is an input-only argument and should be of type uint32_t. It holds
 * a UCS-4 encoded Unicode character that is to be converted to UTF-8. If
 * val is given as a function it is executed only once.
 * @param tmp is a temporary variable and should be of type uint8_t. It
 * represents an intermediate value during conversion that is to be
 * output by PUT_BYTE.
 * @param PUT_BYTE writes the converted UTF-8 bytes to any proper destination.
 * It could be a function or a statement, and uses tmp as the input byte.
 * For example, PUT_BYTE could be "*output++ = tmp;" PUT_BYTE will be
 * executed up to 4 times for values in the valid UTF-8 range and up to
 * 7 times in the general case, depending on the length of the converted
 * Unicode character.
 */
#define PUT_UTF8(val, tmp, PUT_BYTE)\
    {\
        int bytes, shift;\
        uint32_t in = val;\
        if (in < 0x80) {\
            tmp = in;\
            PUT_BYTE\
        } else {\
            bytes = (av_log2(in) + 4) / 5;\
            shift = (bytes - 1) * 6;\
            tmp = (256 - (256 >> bytes)) | (in >> shift);\
            PUT_BYTE\
            while (shift >= 6) {\
                shift -= 6;\
                tmp = 0x80 | ((in >> shift) & 0x3f);\
                PUT_BYTE\
            }\
        }\
    }

/**
 * @def PUT_UTF16(val, tmp, PUT_16BIT)
 * Convert a 32-bit Unicode character to its UTF-16 encoded form (2 or 4 bytes).
 * @param val is an input-only argument and should be of type uint32_t. It holds
 * a UCS-4 encoded Unicode character that is to be converted to UTF-16. If
 * val is given as a function it is executed only once.
 * @param tmp is a temporary variable and should be of type uint16_t. It
 * represents an intermediate value during conversion that is to be
 * output by PUT_16BIT.
 * @param PUT_16BIT writes the converted UTF-16 data to any proper destination
 * in desired endianness. It could be a function or a statement, and uses tmp
 * as the input byte.  For example, PUT_BYTE could be "*output++ = tmp;"
 * PUT_BYTE will be executed 1 or 2 times depending on input character.
 */
#define PUT_UTF16(val, tmp, PUT_16BIT)\
    {\
        uint32_t in = val;\
        if (in < 0x10000) {\
            tmp = in;\
            PUT_16BIT\
        } else {\
            tmp = 0xD800 | ((in - 0x10000) >> 10);\
            PUT_16BIT\
            tmp = 0xDC00 | ((in - 0x10000) & 0x3FF);\
            PUT_16BIT\
        }\
    }\



#include "mem.h"

#ifdef HAVE_AV_CONFIG_H
#    include "internal.h"
#endif /* HAVE_AV_CONFIG_H */

#endif /* AVUTIL_COMMON_H */

/*
 * The following definitions are outside the multiple inclusion guard
 * to ensure they are immediately available in intmath.h.
 */

#ifndef av_ceil_log2
#   define av_ceil_log2     av_ceil_log2_c
#endif
#ifndef av_clip
#   define av_clip          av_clip_c
#endif
#ifndef av_clip64
#   define av_clip64        av_clip64_c
#endif
#ifndef av_clip_uint8
#   define av_clip_uint8    av_clip_uint8_c
#endif
#ifndef av_clip_int8
#   define av_clip_int8     av_clip_int8_c
#endif
#ifndef av_clip_uint16
#   define av_clip_uint16   av_clip_uint16_c
#endif
#ifndef av_clip_int16
#   define av_clip_int16    av_clip_int16_c
#endif
#ifndef av_clipl_int32
#   define av_clipl_int32   av_clipl_int32_c
#endif
#ifndef av_clip_uintp2
#   define av_clip_uintp2   av_clip_uintp2_c
#endif
#ifndef av_sat_add32
#   define av_sat_add32     av_sat_add32_c
#endif
#ifndef av_sat_dadd32
#   define av_sat_dadd32    av_sat_dadd32_c
#endif
#ifndef av_clipf
#   define av_clipf         av_clipf_c
#endif
#ifndef av_popcount
#   define av_popcount      av_popcount_c
#endif
#ifndef av_popcount64
#   define av_popcount64    av_popcount64_c
#endif
```

The error is on the line: if ((a+0x80000000u) & ~UINT64_C(0xFFFFFFFF)) return (a>>63) ^ 0x7FFFFFFF;

Answer (score 1):

C files cannot be compiled as CLR, as stated by the [`D8045`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abb82cy0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) error description.

So you need to compile your `encoder.c` file as **C++**. You can use the **/TP** option file on this file for this.

**Edit:**

By right-clicking on a specific file in your solution explorer, you can set individual compilation settings, per-file.

**Edit 2:**

Now it seems you missed some includes... Where does the `encoder.c` file come from?

About the `UINT64_C` macro, it should be safe to define it as:

```
#ifndef UINT64_C
    #define UINT64_C( _n_ ) ( _n_ ## ULL )
#endif
```

Comment: In the C/C++ > Advanced > Compile AS it set to: Compile as C++ Code (/TP) this is the only option with /TP

Comment: You need to do it on the `encoder.c` file, not on your projects settings.

Comment: If you are going to compile it as C++, you might as well make it obvious by just changing the extension to cpp.

Comment: I did on the ecnoder.c file properties changed it to compile as > Compile as C++ Code (/TP) but now i'm getting another error: which wasn't before : Error 1 error C3861: 'UINT64_C': identifier not found this error came up now after changed the encoder.c properties to /TP This is the line in the cnoder.c file where the error is now on and wasn't before: if ((a+0x80000000u) & ~UINT64_C(0xFFFFFFFF)) return (a>>63) ^ 0x7FFFFFFF;

Comment: See the second edit... Maybe you should give us more info about that specific file...

Comment: Now the c/c++ > advanced compile as set to /TP as it was . And i changed the enocder.c property to /TP too soon as i changed the file to /TP i'm getting this unit64_c error. ried to change the encode.c to encoder.cpp but same unit64 error.

Comment: Just edited my question and added the content of the ENCODER.C file maybe something there is wrong ? Again: In the project general properties i set it to : Common Language Runtime Support (/clr) then i had the error with the encoder.c file so i changed the encoder.c file property to /TP and now i have this unit64 error.

Comment: Sorry the error the unit64 is not on the encoder.c is on another file if i click double on the error the file is open the file is: common.h

Comment: Edited again my question with the correct common.h file which the error is there the unit64

Comment: Tried to put this: #ifndef UINT64_C
    #define UINT64_C( _n_ ) ( _n_ ## ULL )
#endif above the error line in the common.h but it gave me many errors when compiling.

Comment: Yes this is the error: Error 1 error C3861: 'UINT64_C': identifier not found d:\c-sharp\c++ compiling\consoleapplication7\ffmpeg_x86\include\libavutil\common.h 176 1